# remove /blog sub from wordpress permalinks

Tags: wordpress

Any idea? Im using wordpress as a CMS (not a blog) and I would like to change the default "blog" subdirectory in something like "news".

Thanks

WP Version 3

Comment: what "blog" subdirectory are you talking about?

Comment: the blog dir in the permalinks

Answer (score 3):

This probably means you've installed workpress in the yoursite.com/blog directory - for example, if you `ftp` into your site, you'll see the `/` folder listed, which is the base directory of your site. Anything in this folder will be served as `yoursite.com/somefile.html`. However, installing wordpress in the `/blog` directory means everything served from wordpress will look like `yoursite.com/blog/wp-admin`, for example.

If you change the name of that subdirectory to `news`, that would solve your problem. Keep in mind, however, that some things inside wordpress will be configured to use that blog directory as the home directory, and simply renaming it might cause unexpected problems.

Hope this helps.

PS - if you actually point us at your site, or give a little bit more technical information about your directory structure, we might be able to help more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a way to rename the "blog" directory, where you installed WordPress to.
   a. One way could be an FTP client you're using.
   b. Another way could be the File Manager in your web host's control panel.

But DO NOT RENAME IT YET.

2. Log in to your WordPress Dashboard.
3. Go to "Settings > General" in the left set of options.
4. Change "WordPress address (URL)" from "http://yourdomain/blog" to "http://yourdomain/news"
   (Don't hit "Save Changes" yet...)
5. Make a similar change to "Site address (URL)"
6. Click "Save Changes"
7. Go rename the "blog" directory to "news"
8. Now visit your site and see what happens.

If you have already added posts with images and such, there will be links in your posts that contain the old "/blog/" part of your path. You will need to update those posts.

Good luck.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named  `"Custom Taxonomies"`. You can use it.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-taxonomies/

Comment: something compatible with wordpress 3 please?

Comment: There are sth there

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/essential-guide-wordpress-custom-taxonomies/

Comment: This is not a solution for the problem at hand - check @Paul's or @Anthony's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from .htaccess adding this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/blog/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/index.php/news/$1 [R=301,L]
```